# Use Data Variable as Vue Template Without Parent Wrapper

Tags: vue.js, codemirror

I am trying to embed a Codemirror instance as a Vue component, similar to what was accomplished in this [project](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror/blob/master/src/codemirror.vue). However, instead of returning a template of the Codemirror instance inside of a parent

```html
<div class="vue-codemirror" :class="{ merge }">
    <!-- Textarea will be replaced by Codemirror instance. -->
    <textarea ref="textarea" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" v-else>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I am simplying trying to return the Codemirror instance alone. The reason why I can't simply remove the parent div and have

```html
<!-- Textarea will be replaced by Codemirror instance. -->
<textarea ref="textarea" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" v-else>
</textarea>
```

is because the method to replace the textarea, `CodeMirror.fromTextArea()`, requires the textarea to have a parentNode. Otherwise, a null error will be encountered.

Luckily, there is a way to create a Codemirror instance without using a textarea at all, `CodeMirror()`. This instance has a function `getWrapperElement()` that returns the DOM node:

```html
<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">
   ...
</div>
```

I want to output this specific DOM node relating to Codemirror instance using the Vue `template`/`render` function. The current way I'm creating the instance is by initializing it in the component `data` object.

```js
data: function () {
    // Create a CodeMirror instance.
    let cm = new CodeMirror(null, {
        ...
    })
    return {
        // Define a CodeMirror instance for each CodeBlockView.
        cm : cm,
        ...
    }
},
```

**Update 1**: I have found one way to do this, albeit very hacker-ish. We use the `createElement` function that is passed in with render and pass into the data object argument the innerHTML of DOM node we want to render. <strike>It seems to be working visually but the CodeMirror instance isn't editable.</strike>

```js
render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement('div', {
        class: this.dom.classList.value,
        domProps: {innerHTML: this.dom.innerHTML}
    })
}
```

**Update 2**: However, this doesn't pass in the actual DOM node rather it only shallowly copies it; this presents a problem as it doesn't allow it to be editable nor have a `CodeMirror` instance attached.

Comment: It seems you need to hide textarea instead of removing completely: `<textarea ref="textarea" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" v-show="!merge"></textarea>`

Comment: The removal of the textarea is done from within the CodeMirror library; I'd prefer not to have to change the original code of that. Is there a way to use the DOM node from `getWrapperElement` as the template to render?

Comment: Using render is a wrong way to do what you want. Prefer using ref instead https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Right now, I have as the `template`: `<textarea ref="textarea"></textarea>`, and the CodeMirror instantiation method is in `mounted`. Based off what I've read on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html, it seems that `this.$refs.textarea.parentNode` shouldn't be null in mounted as `this.$refs.textarea` should be on the actual DOM node. For some reason this leads to a continuous cycle between `mounted` and `created`, crashing my browser window.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the template anymore after the component has been created. It's not a property of the component but a parameter that is passed to the constructor as far as I know.

Hence, you would need to create the CodeMirror instance before the component is created and inject it.

However, I fail to see the problem with a wrapping component, could you explain the why?

Comment: What do you mean by injecting the instance? I'd prefer a no-wrapping component as I am trying to replicate what was done in https://prosemirror.net/examples/codemirror/, with the `contenteditable="false"` and `CodeMirror` on the same div, mainly to avoid later writing something like `div.childElement.CodeMirror.focus()`. I'm pretty new to Vue but avoiding adding another div I hope would be simple.

Comment: Hm, I have found that setting `this.$el = this.CodeMirror.getWrapperElement()` in `mounted` seems to replace the textarea and have that render outwards.

Comment: I didn't know that the $el reference is settable! Interesting. But might be that replacing the DOM element with another one has some negative implications somewhere. But I am not sure whether if it is preferable to replace the elements over referencing an element by id/class.

Answer (score 1):

I test many ways and the most simple template I find was keeping the textarea, after that the component should receive options and value and emit the new value.

[you can test the component here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-giw1t)

I'm not a codeMirror expert, I import many things for keep the codemirror component more flexible, you can adjust the imports with your needs.

```vue
//component codeMirror.vue
<template>
  <textarea ref="myCm"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror';

// language
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
// theme css
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/monokai.css';
// require active-line.js
import 'codemirror/addon/selection/active-line';
// styleSelectedText
import 'codemirror/addon/selection/mark-selection';
import 'codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor';
// hint
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';
// highlightSelectionMatches
import 'codemirror/addon/scroll/annotatescrollbar';
import 'codemirror/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar';

import 'codemirror/addon/search/match-highlighter';
// keyMap
import 'codemirror/mode/clike/clike';
import 'codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets';
import 'codemirror/addon/comment/comment';
import 'codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog';
import 'codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.css';

import 'codemirror/addon/search/search';
import 'codemirror/keymap/sublime';
// foldGutter
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/foldgutter.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/brace-fold';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/comment-fold';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/foldcode';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/foldgutter';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/indent-fold';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/markdown-fold';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/xml-fold';

export default {
  name: 'codeMirror',
  props: {
    value: String, // give to the component a start value
    options: Object, // give the codeMirror options
  },
  mounted() {
    const myCodemirror = new CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.$refs.myCm, this.options);
    myCodemirror.setValue(this.value);
    myCodemirror.on('change', (cm) => {
      if (this.$emit) {
        this.$emit('input', cm.getValue());
      }
    });
  },
};

</script>
```

after that is easy to use this component for render codeMirror in multiple instances, readOnly, recovery de data, multiple templates, no limits. ex:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    Read Only, default theme, value multiple line
    <codeMirror :value="value0" :options="noChanges"></codeMirror>
    Value Dynamic, theme monokai, other extra fancy things
    <codeMirror :value="value" :options="monokai" @input="onCmCodeChange"></codeMirror>
    Only for debug, shows the modifications made inside codemirror
    {{ value }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import codeMirror from '@/components/codeMirror.vue';

export default {
  name: 'pageEditor',
  components: {
    codeMirror,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value0: `let choco: "bombon";
        let type: 'caramel;
        choco + '  ' + type;`,
      value: 'let frankie= "It\'s alive"',
      noChanges: {
        theme: 'default',
        readOnly: true,
        tabSize: 2,
        line: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
      },
      monokai: {
        tabSize: 2,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        line: true,
        foldGutter: true,
        styleSelectedText: true,
        mode: 'text/javascript',
        keyMap: 'sublime',
        matchBrackets: true,
        showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
        theme: 'monokai',
        extraKeys: { Ctrl: 'autocomplete' },
        hintOptions: {
          completeSingle: false,
        },
      },

    };
  },
  methods: {
    onCmCodeChange(newValue) {
      this.value = newValue;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I hope this help